# How to calculate the probability of inheriting a gene?

Tags: probability

This question may be simple for many of you. Me and my son both have webbed toes. This is the information I can find

- Syndactyly occurs in approximately one out of 2500 newborns.

  - In up to approximately 40% of cases, there is a family history of syndactyly.
  - The children of an affected individual will have a 50% chance of having syndactyly.
  - it can skip a generation.
  - and it affect boys twice as often a girls

As I don't believe any other members of my family have it is it more likely to be coincidence than genetics?

How can I calculate the probability of these two options?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Not sure there is enough information here.  On its face, you appear to settle the matter when you say "in $ 40\% $ of cases there is a family history."  But perhaps you mean to suggest that the gene might be present but not manifesting.  If we take that $40\%$ figure to mean that only $40\%$ of cases are inherited, then your answer is clear.  If it means something else, it needs clarification.

Comment: I understand in an individual wonder how me (the mother) having it affects the

Comment: I looked it up.  As to the gene itself, the situation is fairly clear:  it is dominant and not sex-linked.  That means that if exactly one parent has the gene then the child will receive it with probability $.5$  This does not mean that the child will exhibit the condition, however.  The gene is not "fully penetrant" which means it can go unexpressed.  That's why it can "skip a generation".  I could not find any estimates of its degree of penetrance...I don't think it is well understood. N.B. I am no expert in this field, I just did a quick scan of some literature.

Comment: Sorry..clicked return.. It means the 40% of the manifesting cases. And I understand in an individual has a 40% chance of having inherited it with no other information. But wonder how me (the mother) having it affects the probability if at all. What are the probabilites of two people in the same family having it randomly with no gene involved. Is it still 60%?

Comment: It seems that at .5 it would be a really, really common in my family. As its not a family thing I assumed I fell into the non-inherited 60%. Having a son with it has really confused me.

Comment: These are questions for a geneticist, it's not math.  Given that the gene can be present but "suppressed" I am not sure I'd have any faith in that $40\%$ figure.  Surely it is based on self-reporting and if the gene isn't expressed how would anyone know it was present?  As I say, I was unable to find any published estimate of the degree of penetrancy...that is, the probability that the gene, if present, will be expressed.  I expect (but do not know) that this number is unknown.

Comment: To emphasize:  that probability, the probability that the gene, if present, is expressed is critical in answering your questions.  Your comment that 
"It seems that at .5 it would be really common in my family." is based on the false assumption that the having the gene means exhibiting the condition.   Best I can do!  Sorry I can't say more.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I'll have to wait for the grand children to see. Prehaps I'm the mitochondrial eve of a new strain of webs toes. I'll go with that.

Comment: Excellent plan!